# Maximum entry of small-normed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices such that $\|A-B\|_2< \epsilon $. Can we say something about the maximum entry of $A-B$?

Note: $\|\|_2$ refers to the spectral norm.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A=[a_{i,j}]$ satisfies $||A||_2\leq \epsilon$. Then (with the Frobenius norm) $||A||_F\leq \sqrt{n}||A||_2\leq \sqrt{n}\epsilon$. Then, for every $(i,j)$, $|a_{i,j}|\leq \sqrt{n}\epsilon$. (the Dumpster's result is false -he forgot the square root-).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\|\|_2$ refers to the Frobenius norm, we have the obvious statement
$$\text{MaxElement}(A-B)<\sqrt{\epsilon}$$
where $\text{MaxElement}$ returns the element with largest absolute value, but I'm not sure you can say anything stronger.

### Edit 1:

To prove this, note that if $A-B$ has an element larger than $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, then

$$\|A-B\|_2=\sum_{i,j}(A-B)^2_{ij}>(A-B)_{i_\text{max}j_\text{max}}>(\sqrt{\epsilon})^2=\epsilon$$
which contradicts $\|A-B\|_2< \epsilon$. Meanwhile, if all elements are zero except one which is smaller than $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, then
$$\|A-B\|_2=\sum_{i,j}(A-B)^2_{ij}=(A-B)_{i_\text{max}j_\text{max}}<(\sqrt{\epsilon})^2=\epsilon$$
which satisfies $\|A-B\|_2< \epsilon$. So the bound is tight.

Comment: And I was referring to the spectral norm.

Comment: @EricGregor: Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the spectral norm case.